# Expresión regular entre etiquetas

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

necesito ayuda con una expresión regular. Necesito obtener de un HTML todas las etiquetas DIV, por ejemplo:

```
<div>lo que sea...</div>
```

Bien, ese ejemplo es fácil, el problema lo tengo cuando adentro de un div tengo otro div, ya que no me sirve seleccionar desde que abre hasta que cierra la etiqueta  porque debo fijarme que no exista otra etiqueta div que este abriendo en el medio. Ejemplo:

```
<div>.... 
     <div> child </div>
</div>
```

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

Comment: ¿Te importa que se repitan los `<div>` anidados? ¿Prefieres hacer la búsqueda usando el soporte para DOM de PHP?

Comment: No, no me importa que se repitan. El problema que tengo para usar DOMDocument es que el HTML que tengo que procesar viene roto, puede tener un div adentro de un span, clases o estilos vacios, justamente tengo que corregirlo.

Comment: ¿Quieres validar un `HTML` de forma similar a [esta herramienta en línea](https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator)? De ser así, puedes probar también con [esta función](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51422238/4146962).

Comment: Hay dos problemas con una solución basada con regexes: La primera es que la expresión regular es relativamente compleja y susceptible a fallos con un DOM incorrecto. La segunda es que devolvería el div y todo su contenido y seguiría buscando a partir de ahí. Por lo tanto, para devolver los divs "interiores" se tendría que buscar dentro de lo devuelto, probablemente con recursividad. Lo mejor es usar un parseador html. Prueba con: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Perfecto, al final estoy utilizando la clase DOMDocument, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución con expresiones regulares es bastante frágil. Hay muchas situaciones en las que un HTML se vuelve bastante complejo y al regex habría que seguir agregándole condiciones extra hasta llegar a una expresión gigante y complicada.

Pero si asumimos que el HTML es muy sencillo como en el ejemplo que mostraste, te cuento cómo sería.

En primera instancia partimos de la expresión que coincide con un solo tag, en el que no haya ningún caracter `<`. Es decir, que no se abra un tag hijo

```
%<div[^>]*>[^<]*</div[^>]*>%i
```

Y a esa expresión le agregamos en el medio una expresión para que coincida con cualquier tag que no sea `<div...>` ni `</div...>`

```
%<(?!/?div[\s>])[^>]*>%i
```

que obviamente puede estar seguido de más caracteres intermedios `[^<]*`, y todo esto puede repetirse infinitamente

```
%(?:<(?!/?div[\s>])[^>]*>[^<]*)*%i
```

Bien, agregando esta última en el medio de la primera expresión que teníamos, nos queda una expresión que coincide con un `div` entero que puede tener otros tags (no divs) anidados

```
%<div[^>]*>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?div[\s>])[^>]*>[^<]*)*</div[^>]*>%i
```

Hasta acá todo normal. Ahora viene lo interesante. Vamos a usar recursividad. `(?R)` es una estructura que actúa como si fuera todo tu patrón completo. O sea, vuelve a llamar a todo tu regex desde el inicio como si fuese una subrutina recursiva.

Usando `(?R)` logramos hacer que el patrón coincida con infinitos divs anidados. Simplemente lo ponemos como alternativa en donde coincidíamos con otros tags. Nos queda:

```
%<div[^>]*>[^<]*(?:(?:<(?!/?div[\s>])[^>]*>|(?R))[^<]*)*</div[^>]*>%i
```

Código:

```
$regex = '%<div[^>]*>[^<]*(?:(?:<(?!/?div[\s>])[^>]*>|(?R))[^<]*)*</div[^>]*>%i';

$texto = '<div>.... 
     <div> child </div>
</div>';

preg_match_all($regex, $texto, $resultado);

var_dump($resultado);
```

Igualmente, mi respuesta apunta a explicar la expresión regular que responde a la pregunta. Sin embargo, mi recomendación es que uses funciones para procesar el DOM. Están pensadas para lo que estás haciendo, son mucho más sencillas y no te van a fallar cuando por ejemplo tengas algo como `<input type="text" value="<div> que rompe todo">`.